# How to access a loop's variable from a function?

Tags: php

I have a loop which will make calls to the function. Variables are defined (and reassigned on each iteration) in the first loop which are required for the function to function.

Loop:

```
if ($something) {
    while (!$recordSet->EOF) {
       $variable1 = TRUE;
       $variable2 = FALSE;
       ...
       function1()
    }
}
```

Function:

```
function function1() {
   if ($variable1 && !$variable2) {
      ...
   }
}
```

The variables will have boolean values, and the environment is limited to PHP 4.

I'm currently considering using `global $variable1;` in the while loop and function1, but I know globals are almost always frowned upon.

Usually I'd use `define("variable1","a value")`, but the values will be changed multiple times.

Any suggestions, or is global defining the best solution in this case?

Thanks.

EDIT: Totally forgot to mention. This file is actually a spaghetti legacy code, and function1 is called in a hundred different places, all with varying bits of information. Otherwise, I would have used arguments.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Comment: Sorry, updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main scope, define `global $variable1` and `global $varible2`.

Also do it in the function. 
But this is the worst solution. You will confuse, if these variables changes somewhere else.

The best way I think is to refactore your code, and pass varables as parameters.

The other solution could be create a class for these 2 variables, and set/get them statically.

```
class variablesPlaceHolder {

    private static $variable1;

    private static $variable2;

    public static function getVariable1() {
        return self::$variable1;
    }

    public static function getVariable2() {
        return self::$variable2;
    }

    public static function setVariable1($variable1) {
        self::$variable1 = $variable1;
    }

    public static function setVariable2($variable2) {
        self::$variable2 = $variable2;
    }
}
```

And the include this class in file, where you want to use them, and call `variablesPlaceHolder::setVariable1(anyValue)` `variablesPlaceHolder::getVariable1()`

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was currently leaning towards. It's not ideal, but it will do the job. Problem with refactoring is that the page is 3k+ lines, about 40 are my own, and countless other files rely on it (report generating script). Think this will have to be it.

Comment: I edited my comment, please check it. With this placeholder class you cant overwrite directly the values of variables.

Comment: The variables *need* to be able to change value though, on each iteration of the loop they may change.

Comment: But you can. Just call the variablesPlaceHolder::setVariable1(anyValue); in the loop, and variablesPlaceHolder::getVariable1(); in the function.

Comment: Ah, I guess I misread your previous comment. Thanks, I'm going to stick with globals for now, but will look into this when I (one day!) get approval to refactor the whole thing. Marked as answer.